# workflow in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I'm using ShgarePoint designer 2010,
I have created custom list.

I have associate workflow to this list and operate the workflow on list item.

now I want to make some change in the workflow, but I cant get into the workflow.
how can I open old workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you have created a List Workflow for a SharePoint Custom List. If you created it in SharePoint Designer 2010 you go to the Workflows object in the Navigation pane on the right side. Open the workflow you created and click Edit workflow under the Customization tab.